# Computing the Interaction gain. Is there an Error in the infotheo package in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, information-theory

In order to implementing a certain feature selection method for a classification problem I need to estimate the the interaction the interaction gain between two features and the target variable which is defined as:
$$
I(F_i;F_j;C) = I(F_i;C|F_j) - I(F_i;C)
$$
I found the infotheo package on cran which estimates this with MLE. There is a direct function interinformation() and also the functions condinformation() and mutinformation() to estimate the left side of the equation. Now, when I do both estimation I get exactly the same result, but with different signs. See the following code using the xor problem where the interaction gain should be positive:

```
#### randomly generate binary variables from a bernoulli distribution
set.seed(1234)
f1 <- rbinom(n=50,size=1,prob=0.5)
f2 <- rbinom(n=50,size=1,prob=0.5)

## creat target using xor operation of the two feature: f1 XOR f2
#  this mean that target is 1 if f1[i]!=f2[i] and 0 otherwise
target <- ifelse(f1==f2,0,1)
xor <- data.frame(target,f1,f2)

# load infotheo packages
library(infotheo)

##### compute the interaction gain directly using the interinformation() function
interinformation(data.frame(xor[,"f1"],xor[,"f2"],
                            xor[,"target"]), method="emp")
# [1] -0.6413717

############ compute the interaction gain with I(F_1;target;|F_2) - I(F_1;target)
# compute I(F_1;target;|F_2)
I_cond <- condinformation(X=xor[,"f1"], Y=xor[,"target"], S=xor[,"f2"], 
                     method="emp")

# compute I(F_1;target)
I <- mutinformation(X=xor[,"f1"], Y=xor[,"target"], method="emp")

I_cond - I
# [1] 0.6413717
## exacly the opposite sign 
# but I(X;Y;Z) = I(X;Z|Y) - I(X;Z)
# error in interinformation() function or other meaning?
```

Now, did I missunderstand the interinformation function or the meaning of the interaction gain or is there an error in the infotheo package? If yes, which of the two solution is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is incorrect: Interaction + Icond = MI (if you draw Venn diagrams, this formula should be evident, though you should be quite careful with three-variate Venn diagrams because if they do offer a valid way to get the correct formulas, they do not offer a faithful representation of IT quantities anymore mainly because interaction informations can be negative)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I was confused because the authors of the papers: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320315000850 and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950705112002699 defined the interaction gain with the equation i wrote above.